# Can I create an in-memory table in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, in-memory-database

is there any possibility to create a database or table with "in-memory" option using SQL Server 2012?. I've been reading about that and I can use that option but working with SQL Server 2014 and still don't know if 2012 is capable to do that.

Anny help appreciated

Answer (score 6):

No, the [In-Memory Optimization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133186%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) was introduced with SQL 2014.